# How to get data from crystal report viewer's fields to local variables in C# or VB.Net?

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, crystal-reports

I need to get data from reports fields to open others windows forms or other reports, How I can get the values of reports fields to pass to local C# o VB.net variables ?

After many time ...

With this upgrade making click on any Textobject on the Report the ClickPage event fire and in that sub is possible to get the Textobject data.

You have to upgrade to Crystal Report 2008 SP 3.6, Link bellow

And Work Fine !!!

https://websmp230.sap-ag.de/sap(bD1lcyZjPTAwMQ==)/bc/bsp/spn/bobj_download/main.htm

```
Private Sub crViewer_ClickPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageMouseEventArgs) Handles crViewer.ClickPage

    If Not IsNothing(e.ObjectInfo.Text) Then

        Clipboard.Clear()
        Clipboard.SetText(e.ObjectInfo.Text)


        Me.CallBackForm(e.ObjectInfo.Name.ToUpper.Trim, e.ObjectInfo.Text)

    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is at a higher level. You want to use "variables", perhaps in the form of a DataTable, and bind that to the Crystal Report. This allows separation of your data access (in a Data Access Layer) from your presentation, and prevents report data sources from being buried within the oh-so-fun Crystal visual designers. This will allow you to then use the same DataSet for any other part of your application - in answer to your question.

Comment: No.

I need to handle click event in preview form in Crystal Report, when user click on the report I need to capture the data that user clicked

Thx

Comment: No.

Suppose you have a Crystal Report Viewer shwoing sales data, in VB6 Crystal Report Viewer you can make click on invoice number and programatically you can open a window with all information
regarding that invoice BUT ! in VB.NET 2008 Crystal Report Viewer you can't handle that !

What is the method that I can use to making click on Crystal Report Viewer Form can open a windows with the data of that invoice I clicked ?